# Update month in DateTime using Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm using a library that returns a DateTime like so:

```
2020-02-10 12:00:00.000Z
```

And I need to update its month (just this) like so:

```
2020-03-10 12:00:00.000Z
```

I tried something like this:

```
DateTime newDate = new DateTime(
 oldDate.year,
 oldDate.month + 1,
 oldDate.day,
 oldDate.hour,
);
```

This gives something like this output:

```
2020-03-10 12:00:00.000
```

But it's not quite the same (it's missing the last part)

Can I change **just** the month?

Comment: no, from 1. But sorry, not sure what you mean by that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You achieve using Datetime utc method.

```
DateTime oldDate = DateTime.now();

DateTime newDate=  DateTime.utc( oldDate.year, oldDate.month + 1, oldDate.day,oldDate.hour,oldDate.minute);

print(newDate.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Something you *could* do which will work for if the `DateTime` you want to change is UTC or not is make an extension method for `DateTime` objects:

```
extension DateTimeExtensions on DateTime {
    DateTime addMonths(int months) {
      if (this.isUtc) {
        return DateTime.utc(this.year, this.month + months, this.day, this.hour, this.minute, this.second, this.millisecond);
      } else {
        return DateTime(this.year, this.month + months, this.day, this.hour, this.minute, this.second, this.millisecond);
      }
   }
}
```

This of course requires you to be using a version of Dart >= 2.7 which you can update in your `pubspec.yaml`.

If you don't want to use Dart 2.7 or above then you can do something along the lines of:

```
class DateTimeHelpers {
    static DateTime addMonths(DateTime dateTime, int months) {
      if (dateTime.isUtc) {
        return DateTime.utc(dateTime.year, dateTime.month + months, dateTime.day, dateTime.hour, dateTime.minute, dateTime.second, dateTime.millisecond);
      } else {
        return DateTime(dateTime.year, dateTime.month + months, dateTime.day, dateTime.hour, dateTime.minute, dateTime.second, dateTime.millisecond);
      }
   }
}
```